# switching power sources

Tags: power

I have a small project I am working on that accepts power from either a 5v DC power source or a USB power source.

Now, I know that both of the power sources are effectively 5v. I have measured the power on both with my meter and can see that the USB supply is at 5.4 and the DC supply is at 5.01v.

I would like to be able to build something that switches over to the USB supply when the cable is connected. However, I have never done this before. I have taken a look around on Google already and have read some things about P Channel MosFETs and PowerPath controllers - but I am a little confused as to whether the two incoming voltages I have are suitable for this?

Would someone be able to give me a little advice on this at all?

Cheers,

Rafa

Comment: You might get a useful response here, but this sounds like something that would be better asked on http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just a side note: 5.4V on a USB supply is outside of specs. It should be 5.25V maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Consider copying the [Arduino Uno reference design](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf).  This is part of that schematic showing the MOSFET used to turn on / off the USB power when the barrel jack power source is active:

[image]

Comment: actually, just the part of picture containing mosfet on the left would suffice.

Comment: It's more of a personal preference, but I never liked it when someone post a bit of a schematic and a key net name (in this case "+5V") is missing the source of the signal.  That's why when I copied the schematic I included the 5 volt regulator on the right.